# Differentaibility Check of a Function

Tags: functions, derivatives, graphing-functions, absolute-value

I have this function:
[image]

and I know that the graph looks like this:
[image]

Where is this function non differentiable?I know that the absolute value function is non-differentiable at x=0, but what happens in this case at s=1,s=-1? is g differntiable there?

Comment: Looking at its graph, do you think that there’s a consistent single value of its slope at these points?

Comment: No, I understand that there is a problem there when it comes to differentiability. I am looking for the mathematical way to show it properly

Comment: The same way you would for $\lvert x\rvert$: one possibility is to show that the limit of the difference quotient doesn’t exist.

Comment: For instance lim [(g(s)-g(1))/(s-1)] as s approaches 1?

Comment: "I am looking for the mathematical way to show it properly". Then you should read carefully the definition of differentiable (at a point).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_of_real_functions_of_one_variable

Answer (score 3):

At $s=1$ the right hand derivative is $0$ and left hand derivative is $1$.

At $s=-1$ the right hand derivative is $-1$ and left hand derivative is $0$.
 So the function is not differentiable at these points.